# combine itertools 2 product with specified amount of variables

Tags: python, string, list, python-itertools

i am tryin to make a product that has 2 lists with 3 variables each combined into 1 list/product

i am trying to combine 3 letters and 3 numbers so i am using string for those
this is psuedo code
`

```
product(string.ascii_lowercase, repeat=int(3)) + product(string.digits, repeat=int(3))
```

`i have gotten thi working but this goes through all letters before combining with numbers so its rather slow`

```
product(string.ascii_lowercase+ string.digits, repeat=int(6))
```

`

Comment: is there something that makes you think it would be faster to not go through them all at once ?

Comment: not quite sure i understand the question but i am trying to make a brute-force code that goes through every possible combination of 3 lower case letters and 3 numbers combined example: abc123

Comment: what do you mean by `i have gotten this working but this goes through all letters before combining with numbers so its rather slow`? why do you think it would be faster to not go through all the letters?  .... if you are trying to do something other than just get all the combinations and you only need "some special" combinations there maybe faster ways to find those

Comment: the password always has the format: letter letter letter number number number so it is rather slow because it starts printing aaaaaa but if i could make it start printing for example aaa000 that would skip the unnecessary letter combining

Answer (score 0):

basically create two iterators like you are

```
alphas = product(string.ascii_lowercase, repeat=int(3))
numerics = product(string.digits, repeat=int(3))
```

turn it into lists instead of iterators

```
alphas = list(alphas)
numerics = list(numerics)
```

then just get the product of those two

```
potential_solutions = product(alphas,numerics)
for combo in potential_solutions:
    print(combo[0] + combo[1])
```

and you should get something that looks like your passwords .... its still alot of combinations ... but its pretty fast